# Automatic Call Recorder Pro won't play recorded sound files

Tags: calls

I have installed [Automatic Call Recorder Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder) along with [Automatic Call Recorder Free] play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.four.fox.automaticcallrecorderfree. The problem is that when I open any of these two apps I see the recorded files but they won't play. When I press the play button it temporarily changes to a pause button but within less than a second it turns back to a play button and no audio is played. This happens with all sound files. I had to install [Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=polis.app.callrecorder) in order to be able to play my files. Why is Automatic Call Recorder not playing my recorded files?